# reach to certain commit and discard all the commits that were done ahead of it

Tags: git, github

I have merged the master branch into my feature branch. However, commit did not go well. and it messed up the changes that were suppose to come from master. feature branch is 45 commits ahead and these are the latest 4 ahead commit in it:

[image]

now i need to reach to commit a3aec79. and discard all the commits that were done after this particular commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to undo that merge commit and set your feature branch back to the exact state it was right before master was merged into it, then you can do this:

```
git checkout feature
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This assumes that there was nothing else done in the feature branch since you did the merge.

`HEAD^` Is a shorthand notation in git cli to mean "the previous commit". In your case, the feature branch points to a specific commit. Since we know that commit is a merge commit (merging master into the feature branch), then we know that the first parent of that merge commit will be the previous state of the feature branch. The `git reset` command will take your current branch, and force it to point to a different commit. So, we put both of those facts to use by running the above commands and viola! your back in business.

Answer (score 2):

For what I can tell, you just need to do a `git reset a3aec79`. If you want to discard the working copy changes, use the `--hard` flag.

If you already pushed the commits ahead, you'll have to use `git push --force`. In that case would be better to revert instead of reset.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out to a newer branch before just to be safe.

```
git checkout -b bug_fix
```

You can get the commit id that you want to switch to and use:

```
git revert <commit_id>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i ended up solving this issue.

**Step 1:**  Use reset hard command along with sha of the commit till which you want to traverse to.

```
git reset --hard <SHAsum of your commit>
```

Which is `git reset --hard a3aec79c1f47f6d8df95f61236fc212556b5c224` in my case.
If you check the status, you will find your branch behind the already pushed commits. Do not pull the changes at this moment.

**Step 2:** Create a new branch from current revision using

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

work for feature/issues on newly created branch.